# WKScriptMessage.body causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: javascript, swift, macos, exc-bad-access, wkwebview

I'm using the [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKWebView) component in my Mac app to show a webpage. This webpage send data to the native app using JavaScript call `webkit.messageHandlers["callbackHandlerName"].postMessage(dataObject);`

I can receive most of the messages in my native app without problems (and then transform their bodies to `NSDictionary`), but some types of messages causes the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I trying to access property `message.body`. I can't find out why some data cannot be send to the native app and other can (in both cases data are nested JavaScript objects)

```
internal func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage)
{
    switch (message.name)
    {
        case "nativeCallbackA":
            onNativeCallbackA(message.body)
        case "nativeCallbackB":
            onNativeCallbackB(message.body) //throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        default:
            print("Unsupported message " + message.name);
    }
}
```

Is there any limitations for messages passed to the native app using the JS `postMessage` call?

Comment: can it be that some of your messages doesn't have a `body` perhaps? Could you check if `body` was nil before trying to do something with it?

Comment: I can't check it, because "Value of type 'AnyObject' can never be nil". Also, my nativeCallbackB has empty body

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh! I solved my problem:

My handler `nativeCallbackB` was declared as:

`func nativeCallbackB(data: Any) { //... }`

but type of `WKScriptMessage.body` is `AnyObject`

So, I changed the declaration of handler to:

`func nativeCallbackB(data: AnyObject) { //... }`

and now it works (but I still don't know why some some messages works also with incorrect declaration of handler and why these problems are not checked by Xcode before compilation)